# Can someone recommend any Dhikr to remove sins?

Tags: forgiveness, dhikr

Aoa

Can anyone please provide me some dhikrs that can get me hasanah any dhikr or any dhikr that can erase sins..MAJOR OR MINOR are there any hadiths?..Jazak Allah

Comment: This is not even Related ???

Comment: Sins canbe removed by repentance.

Comment: Indeed, thank you

Answer (score 1):

### **Dhikr**

Saying these Dhikr can help erase sins one has committed.

- **La ilaha ilallah wahdahu la shareeka lah, lahul
  mulku wala hul hamd yuhyi wa yumeet, wahuwa 'ala kulli shayin'  qader**  100 times in a day is a way to get Allah to forgive 100 sins.
- **Subhanallahi wa bihamdihi** 100 times in a day is a easier way to get Allah to forgive your sins even if your sins were as much as the foam in the ocean.

People say that hadith about dhikr that gets Allah to forgive you only applies to minor sins.

Answer (score 0):

Assalamu Alaikum,

You must have come across some good answers to your queries. Here I am going to mention one for your reference,

After every prayer in a day, You can recite 'Subhanallah - (33 times), Alhumdulillah - (33 times), Allahu Akbar - (33 times) and Laa Ilaaha Illallahu Wahdahu Laa Shareeka Lahu, Lahul Mulku Wa Lahul Hamdu, Wa Huwa Alaa Kulli Shay'in Qadeer' - last time' that's how you complete 100.

It is stated in Hadith, that when you do this, all your minor sins will be wiped away.

Thank you

Comment: Thank you brother/sister